# Acumatica Prepare Replenishment Screen ProcessAll Action not working

Tags: c#, soap, acumatica

I am on Acumatica 5.30.1672 and am using the SOAP API for Screen IN508000 to try and run the Prepare Replenishment process. I am setting the WarehouseID for where I want to prepare replenishment. The API call is returning the correct InventoryIDs in the `response` object but when I tell it to ProcessAll, it is not. There is no error, just no processing. I feel like I am missing something trivial here but I just cannot see it. When I do this using the GUI, everything works perfectly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AcumaticaTest.AcumaticaWebReference;

namespace AcumaticaTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Screen context = new Screen();
            context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
            context.Timeout = 1200000;

            context.Url = "url to SOAP API Endpoint";
            LoginResult lresult = context.Login("<username>", "<password>");


            IN508000Content IN508000 = context.IN508000GetSchema();
            context.IN508000Clear();

            var commands = new Command[]
                                {
                                        new Value {Value = "<WarehouseID>", LinkedCommand = IN508000.Selection.Warehouse, Commit= true },
                                        new Value {Value = "false", LinkedCommand = IN508000.Selection.Me, Commit= true },
                                        IN508000.ItemsRequiringReplenishment.InventoryID,
                                        IN508000.Actions.ProcessAll
                                };
            var response = context.IN508000Submit(commands);

            var status = context.IN508000GetProcessStatus();
            while (status.Status == ProcessStatus.InProcess)
            {
                status = context.IN508000GetProcessStatus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it is working just fine - the system prepares the replenishment plans for the items of the requested warehouse, and the response object contains all the items that would be listed if you opened the Prepare Replenishment screen with the parameters you set. If you want to e-mail me URL and credentials to your site (gmichaud at acumatica) I can take a look to see what's wrong.

Please note that you don't need to explicitly set `Commit = true` for these two fields (the schema object already has them set to true). I would also recommend to add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` in your loop to avoid hammering the server with requests while it is processing.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. We have actually tracked the issue back to customization that was done by a different team. When we removed their customization, this worked perfectly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @MatthewCrews thanks for the update, glad to hear the issue is resolved! Do not hesitate to reach out if you have other questions.